# Mysql Perdeu Tabelas?

Tags: php, mysql

Acabei de ter uma experiência estranha com mysql, tenho uma base de dados com 8 tabelas no meu local server. De uma hora para outra meu sistema não queria mais fazer login, fui verificar no phpmyadmin e mostrava as tabelas, mas quando eu dava select recebia a mensagem:

```
Table 'sistema.cliente' doesn't exist
```

Perdi meu banco? pois não fiz backup do conteúdo.
OBS: Não é servidor de produção.

Comment: Você já deu um `SHOW TABLES`?

Comment: Não dá para saber. Se você não excluiu manualmente nem deu um comando do tipo `DROP TABLE` não deve ter perdido, mas a certeza depende de você atualizar a página e listar as tabelas. Possivelmente você só está olhando o banco de dados errado ou o nome da tabela está incorreto, mas vários comandos podem excluir sua tabela, por exemplo para importar uma "nova" por cima.

Comment: Sim, usei um SHOW TABLES e retornou 0. Fui dar um drop database e recebi um erro "Error dropping database errno: 66"

Comment: Será que você não está usando o banco de dados errado?

Comment: cheque o DB para ver se não tem erros. o MySQL vem com  ferramentas para isso.

Comment: Já fiz, o banco aparece no phpmyadmin, eu consigo acessa-lo mas ele mostra no menu esquerdos as tabelas no no direito não aparece, e se eu selecionar a tabela no menu esquerdo diz que ela não existe.